# Latex tablenotes margin

Tags: tables, footnotes

I have re-sized a latex table in order to fit in to a two column document as shown in the code below. After that, the table notes seem to be flushed to the left side. I would like to have the table notes aligned with left and right side of the table.

```
\documentclass[layout=twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} 
\usepackage{threeparttable}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{table}[htb] 
   \caption{My data}{\label{T:Table1}}
   \begin{threeparttable}
   \footnotesize \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%\centering
        \begin{tabular}{l l lll }
           \hline
            test1 &test2 &  test3 &test4& test5  \\
           \hline\hline
            AA &  1      & 2      & 3   & 4   \\
            \hline\hline
         \end{tabular}}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para]
         \footnotesize
         \item I want to set the right side margin to the end of the table. The item is flushedto left side of thetable
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add a complete MWE?

Comment: I have added a MWE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you do not use `tabularx`. To use `resizebox` you need to include also the `threeparttable` environment. See below.

```
\documentclass[layout=twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} 
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}  
\begin{table}[htb] 
   \caption{My data}{\label{T:Table1}}
   \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
         \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{l l lll }
           \hline
            test1 &test2 &  test3 &test4& test5  \\
           \hline\hline
            AA &  1      & 2      & 3   & 4   \\
            \hline\hline
         \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}[para]
      \footnotesize
             \item I want to set the right side margin to the end of the table. The item is flushedto left side of thetable
         \end{tablenotes}
 \end{threeparttable}}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htb] 
   \caption{My data}{\label{T:Table2}}
         \begin{threeparttable}
             \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{X l lll }
           \hline
            test1 &test2 &  test3 &test4& test5  \\
           \hline\hline
            AA &  1      & 2      & 3   & 4   \\
            \hline\hline
         \end{tabularx}
        \begin{tablenotes}[para]
      \footnotesize
             \item I want to set the right side margin to the end of the table. The item is flushedto left side of thetable
         \end{tablenotes}
 \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```